# Does magic jack work on Ubuntu?

Tags: phone

Does magic jack work with Ubuntu? I originally had my magic jack on a computer with windows XP and I decided to switch to Ubuntu but I still want Magic jack.

Comment: Have you plugged it?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work out of the box.
Apparently magic jack itself was developing linux drivers but they terminated the project.
there are some ways to get it to work though.

If you connect your magic jack with your router you can use it with the guide at the bottom of [this page](http://www.phoneservicesupport.com/how-can-i-run-majic-jack-on-linux-t11544.html)

If you connect your magic jack with your pc you will need to run it with a virtual machine
You can use [this guide](http://www.broadbandreports.com/forum/r20977358-Successfully-setup-Ubuntu-Linux-VMWare-XP-MagicJack)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It does seem that someone has managed to get MagicJack [working in Linux](http://www.phoneservicesupport.com/magicjack-runs-natively-on-linux-t8566.html), at least, as of 2010. Beware, however, as it appears this solution is rather technical and may void your warranty and/or violate your terms of service.

It may also be possible to get it working [using your router](http://www.phoneservicesupport.com/how-can-i-run-majic-jack-on-linux-t11544.html) with MagicJack Plus.

MagicJack said they were going to support Linux [in September 2011](http://service.liveperson.net/hc/s-61732089/cmd/kbresource/kb-3900972669580632713/view_question!PAGETYPE?sq=Linux&sf=101113&sg=2&st=164588&documentid=345414&action=view), but as of [June 2013](http://service.liveperson.net/hc/s-61732089/cmd/kbresource/kb-3900972669580632713/view_question!PAGETYPE?sq=Linux&sf=101113&st=164588&documentid=345410&action=view), they still don't.

I'd personally recommend going with MagicJack Plus and trying to get it working with your router.

Answer (score 0):

Magic jack Plus does not require a PC in order to work, and can be connected VIA standard cat 5 to your router. Remember, Magic jack requires a broadband connection to the internet either by cable or DSL. The older Magic Jack needs a PC in order to function, in addition to a broadband connection. For Linux users, we can only hope that some Linux guru will develop a driver for it, if that person would be so inclined.