# Ubuntu 14.04 drivers for MagicJack

Tags: drivers

Does MagicJack work on Ubuntu 14.04?  Can I download and install drivers to operate MagicJack on the Ubuntu 14.04 operating system?

Comment: A quick Google search says no.

Comment: Thank you Tim but I feel there has to be a way to accomplish this installation.

Comment: Not necessarily. Sorry. Not everything is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

There was another thread about MagicJack on AskUbuntu here:  [Does magic jack work on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335572/does-magic-jack-work-on-ubuntu)

There seems to be some possibilities.

Magic Jack, though claiming once that they would support Linux has not done so yet, so it could be as Tim said, and not work.

Comment: It does work it just takes some work to get it to work on your computer. It's easier to connect it through your router though. otherwise you'll need a vmbox to get it to work.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).

Answer (score 0):

in my Ubuntu 14.04 install a VMware with windows 7 64bit, I found a MagicJack upgrade file that run in windows, after install the VM windows I plug the usb MajicJack, run the upgrade file and it works perfect, I have this upgrade file that come from MajicJack, if some one needed.. or where can I share this.